# Tomcat - The requested resource () is not available

Tags: java, tomcat6, vaadin

I get this message when I try to start my small test project with Vaadin component on TOmcat server. Funny thing is that It had worked and without any changes at those project or tomcat settings it stopped ??

I read every comment on the net that there is, but hasn't helped. Here is Java code:

```
package com.example.test1_vaadin;

import com.vaadin.Application;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

public class Test1_vaadinApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        Window mainWindow = new Window("Test1_vaadin Application");
        Label label = new Label("Hello Vaadin user");
        mainWindow.addComponent(label);
        setMainWindow(mainWindow);
    }
}
```

And here is web.xml for this application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Test1_Vaadin</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <description>
        Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Test1_vaadin Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>
            Vaadin application class to start</description>
            <param-name>application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.test1_vaadin.Test1_vaadinApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Test1_vaadin Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is also console output that I get in Eclipse when Tomcat is started. I might say that starting Tomcat in console outsice Eclipce works smoothly. OS in Mac OS X:

```
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: .:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:Test1_Vaadin' did not find a matching property.
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Test2_Vaadin' did not find a matching property.
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:simpleaddressbook' did not find a matching property.
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-1971
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 640 ms
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethodN(IntrospectionUtils.java:959)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.CallMethodMultiRule.end(WebRuleSet.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:229)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1138)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2938)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processDefaultWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.defaultWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1075)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name invoker
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2671)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2651)
    ... 38 more
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processDefaultWebConfig
SEVERE: Parse error in default web.xml
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name invoker
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2832)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2938)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processDefaultWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.defaultWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1075)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name invoker
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2671)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2651)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethodN(IntrospectionUtils.java:959)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.CallMethodMultiRule.end(WebRuleSet.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:229)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1138)
    ... 30 more
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processDefaultWebConfig
SEVERE: Occurred at line 386 column 23
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig start
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
21.12.2010 14:49:57 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Poller SunPKCS11-Darwin] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Anybody, any idea?

Comment: You asked 9 questions, none of the answer provided was marked as accepted, nor did you upvote a single answer, try to improve this before asking questions.

Comment: I think I see the problem, but as Alberto says, you're unlikely to get many answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SEVERE: Parse error in default web.xml
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> Servlet mapping specifies an unknown
> servlet name invoker

Your problem is there. You should cultivate the habit of *reading* stack traces, not just posting them somewhere ;-)

Comment: Thanks for help. Well, I found out I just blindly trusted download example. Thanks for reminding me :)